# AWS "Missing required client configuration options" exception with Yii::createObject() default configuration

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get a simple web application working with the Yii 2 framework, a DynamoDB database hosted on AWS and the AWS SDK for PHP. I'm just saving/retrieving movie details to/from the database.

(For the purposes of copying code here, I am not going to copy my real AWS key/secret.)

Everything works as I want when I create my Aws\Sdk object like this:

```
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region'   => 'us-west-2',
    'version'  => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'     => 'KEYKEYKEYKEYKEYKEYKE',
        'secret'  => 'SECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECR'
    ]
]);
$dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
```

But I want to take advantage of Yii's *default configurations* with the Yii::createObject() method, so that I don't have to specify the region, version and credentials every place I create an Aws\Sdk object. So, as per the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#default-configurations), I have saved into my application configuration:

```
\Yii::$container->set('Aws\Sdk', [
    'region'      => 'us-west-2',
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'     => 'KEYKEYKEYKEYKEYKEYKE',
        'secret'  => 'SECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECR'
    ]
]);
```

and now wherever I create an Aws\Sdk object, my code looks like this:

```
$sdk = Yii::createObject('Aws\Sdk');
$dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
```

However, when I do it like this, I get an InvalidArgumentException from AWS about "Missing required client configuration options". If I `var_dump()` the `$sdk` variable immediately after it is assigned, I can see that the object has the required region, version and credentials attributes, but the next line where I assign the `$dynamodb` variable throws the exception.

I am hoping that someone can show me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you shouldn't be putting credentials in your code. I recommend the following:

- If you have this code running on an EC2 instance, instead apply an IAM role to it. With roles you declare exactly what permissions you any CLI/SDK calls that will be running in the instance. When the SDK goes to make a call, [it will contact the instance metadata server and get a set of temporary credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html#instance-profile-credentials). Of course this happens all transparently without you needing to do anything. As the credentials expire after a period of time (your SDK will of course grab new credentials when this happens transparently). This the best option as you no longer need to worry about credentials, other SDKs or the CLI can use it, and it's all temporary.
- [Use a credentials file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html#credential-profiles). You should only really do this if your code is outside of AWS territory and cannot utilize IAM roles. While your credentials become more centralized they're at least not part of your code base where they could potentially be leaked. Also it makes it so that you can easily utilize other languages and still have the credentials automatically pulled up.

Now then on to the other part:

```
\Yii::$container->set('Aws\Sdk', [
    'region'      => 'us-west-2',
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'     => 'KEYKEYKEYKEYKEYKEYKE',
        'secret'  => 'SECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECRETSECR'
    ]
]);
```

This isn't what you think it is, if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/di/Container.php#L252):

> ```
>  * If a class definition with the same name already exists, it will be overwritten with the new one.
>  * You may use [[has()]] to check if a class definition already exists.
>  *
>  * @param string $class class name, interface name or alias name
>  * @param mixed $definition the definition associated with `$class`. It can be one of the following:
>  *
>  * - a PHP callable: The callable will be executed when [[get()]] is invoked. The signature of the callable
>  *   should be `function ($container, $params, $config)`, where `$params` stands for the list of constructor
>  *   parameters, `$config` the object configuration, and `$container` the container object. The return value
>  *   of the callable will be returned by [[get()]] as the object instance requested.
>  * - a configuration array: the array contains name-value pairs that will be **used to initialize the property**
>  *   **values of the newly created object** when [[get()]] is called. The `class` element stands for the
>  *   the class of the object to be created. If `class` is not specified, `$class` will be used as the class name.
>  * - a string: a class name, an interface name or an alias name.
>  * @param array $params the list of constructor parameters. The parameters will be passed to the class
>  * constructor when [[get()]] is called.
>  * @return $this the container itself
>  */
> ```

Note the "**" marked areas. In other words the second parameter is not a set of constructor arguments which is probably what you want, but instead an array of parameters that will be set after your constructor is called. Instead you want your second parameter blank, and the third parameter an array something like:

```
\Yii::$container->set('Aws\Sdk', [], [[
    'region'      => 'us-west-2',
    'version'     => 'latest'
]]);
```

The array within an array looks kind of weird but that's because the parameters array basically goes index by index and set each parameter as positional arguments. Hopefully this helps.